# Unable to access system-wide environment variable in php-fpm

Tags: php, environment-variables

Ubuntu 16.04, php7.0-fpm, apache 2.4, nginx 1.10.0

I added a system-wide environment variable to both possible locations:

```
/etc/environment:
ENVTEST=123

/etc/profile.d/env.sh:
export ENVTEST=123
```

Checking:

```
vagrant@localhost:~$ echo $ENVTEST
123
```

In /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf I pass the variable to PHP:

```
env[ENVTEST] = $ENVTEST
```

But this variable value is a blank string in the $_SERVER array.

If I use a static value in www.conf `env[ENVTEST] = 123` it  works fine.

In console mode I can access the variable value, it doesn't work only in php-fpm mode.

I also tried to set the variable via `SetEnv` in Apache config, but it gives the same result - the variable is set but the value is a blank string.

Comment: I found the solution: include ". /etc/profile.d/env.sh" in apache *envvars* file and add *PassEnv* for each variable in the VirtualHost section.

Comment: Alexey, did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can test the value is set correctly by using the `getenv()` function within your script. I have not found a way to push environment variables safely through a script other than `setenv()`, but if you would it may not push permanent changes to your runtime environment, and might only set it each time you run.

Comment: `getenv()` also returns an empty value. What else can it return if the `$_SERVER['ENVTEST']` value is set but empty?